# Batch Cutting a Raster File using a Moving Extent in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, raster-calculator, lidar

I have a LIDAR file with 20 GB size, and I would like to cut it into smaller areas for gravity terrain correction. **It is more like a moving window processing, with LIDAR as the windowed data, then the window is moved each time to output cropped LIDAR files.** I thought that I could do that using batch processing with this kind of algorithm:

1. Prepare the LIDAR file, close "no data" gaps using SAGA > Close Gaps.
2. Go to raster calculator, put the LIDAR file there as inputs, define output resolution.
3. Define the initial extent and output file naming.
4. Keeping all similar, we use something like expression builder to incrementally change the extent for the subsequent 2nd cropped LIDAR, 3rd cropped LIDAR, and so on.

The only thing I could not understand is how I can build such expression in the batch processing window?

Adding a row there does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS has a [graphical modeler](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html). there you can define inputs, build all the steps of the model and invoke the batch processor and specify inputs. Since now you only have 1 process, it should work.
so it would look something like this. This is too simple, you'll probably want to add an Extent input, and a raster calculator:
[image: simple model, with only 1 operation]
and then invoke as a batch process, define outputs, you're done!